# join two sql queries from two tables with a common variable

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

Below I have a query that finds people within a certain distance (within `$dist = 100;`) from table `'persons'`

```
$origLat = '8.574596';
$origLon = '-73.602050';
$dist = 100; // This is the maximum distance (in miles) away from $origLat, $origLon in which to search
$query = "SELECT id_the_person, Name, Lat, Lng, 3959 * 2 * 
          ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($origLat - Lat)*pi()/180/2),2)
          +COS($origLat*pi()/180 )*COS(Lat*pi()/180)
          *POWER(SIN(($origLon-Lng)*pi()/180/2),2))) 
          as distance FROM persons WHERE 
          Lng between ($origLon-$dist/cos(radians($origLat))*69) 
          and ($origLon+$dist/cos(radians($origLat))*69) 
          and Lat between ($origLat-($dist/69)) 
          and ($origLat+($dist/69))
          having distance < $dist ORDER BY distance limit 100";
```

In this query I find people based on how they matched when they answered questions within table `'svar'`

```
SELECT *, round(count(*)/(SELECT count(*) FROM svar where id_the_person = ?)*100) as pecentage
FROM svar as l
where l.svaret=(
    SELECT m.svaret
    FROM svar as m
    where m.id_the_person = ? and l.id_frag=m.id_frag)
group by (l.id_the_person)
order by pecentage");
```

The variable `id_the_person` is the same in both tables. What I want is the people who matched shorted by percent but only people within the distance according to the first query, i.e. the second query limited to people within `$dist=100`.

Comment: You can use a subquery like so: `SELECT * FROM sample1 s1 WHERE s1.id IN (SELECT s2.id FROM sample2 s2 WHERE s1.test = s2.test)`